# Android keyboard behaviour changed after updated to Jelly Bean

Tags: keyboard, 4.1-jelly-bean

When I am in ICS, whenever I type a wording, followed by `space`, Android will suggest me several useful punctuations like `,`.

I love this behaviour as it is useful to me.

However, now in Jelly Bean, the behaviour is changed. They no longer suggest me punctuations. Instead, when I type "I" followed by `space`, it will suggest me `am`. This is not something what I want.

Is there any where I can fall back to old behaviour?

Comment: You can install ice cream sandwich keyboard from play store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This new feature is called Next word prediction. You can easily disable it to restore the ICS behavior but it's a bit hidden:

1. Go to *Settings > Language & input*
2. Tap on the setting icon beside *Android keyboard* under the *Keyboard & input methods* section
3. At the bottom you'll find *Advanced settings*, tap it
4. There you'll find *Next word prediction*, uncheck it:

[image: Advanced input settings screen]

After that, typing *I* followed by space will bring up the punctuation again instead of predicted words.